# C# WMI method to change registry values works in debug but not release

Tags: c#, wmi, release-mode, remote-registry

I have already done some Googling to see if I could find a solution, but so far I haven't found anything useful. My problem is exactly as the title states. I try to log a remote machine on as a specified user by changing registry values, and it works fine in debug mode, but not release (registry values remain the same). I'm logged into Windows as an admin, and I also use my admin credentials for WMI. The return value is "0" for both cases, which implies there's no error. Another thing to note is that all my other functions that use WMI work fine in both debug and release versions (i.e. WMI queries, WMI Shutdown/Restart/Logoff), so I'm not sure why this specific one won't work in release mode. Here's my code:

```
    public static bool LogOnAsViaWMI(string computerName, string username, string password, string logonUsername, string logonPW)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set connection options
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            options.Username = username;
            options.Password = password;

            // Connect to machine
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computerName + "\\root\\CIMV2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            // Set management class
            ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("StdRegProv");
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, managementPath, null);

            // Set registry values
            if (!SetRegKeyValue(mc, "AutoAdminLogon", "1") ||
                !SetRegKeyValue(mc, "ForceAutoLogon", "1") ||
                !SetRegKeyValue(mc, "DefaultUserName", logonUsername) ||
                !SetRegKeyValue(mc, "DefaultPassword", logonPW) ||
                !SetRegKeyValue(mc, "DefaultDomainName", "MyDomainName"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to set Windows logon registry values");
                return false;
            }

            // Log off to log in as new default
            LogOff(computerName, username, password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool SetRegKeyValue(ManagementClass mc, string valueName, string value)
    {
        // Set values
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("SetStringValue");
        inParams["hDefKey"] = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        inParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";
        inParams["sValueName"] = valueName;
        inParams["sValue"] = value;

        // Invoke inParams
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = mc.InvokeMethod("SetStringValue", inParams, null);
        if (outParams["returnValue"].ToString() != "0")
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue, what happens when you run as administrator?

Comment: When you say release, do you mean outside Visual Studio? Because that would explain it -- debugging it inside VS elevates your process to admin, while running it outside manually doesn't. You have to enable elevation yourself in the manifest file.

Comment: @m.edmondson Sorry i forgot to mentioned I am running as an admin.

Comment: @Blindy I've run both inside and outside VS and I get the same results

Comment: Is your debug version set to run on x86, and your release version set to run on x64?  There are two different registry locations for each.

Comment: @entropic That's it! Can't believe it was that easy/stupid. I totally forgot about setting that in the properties.

Comment: @jmm1487 That's bitten me many times. Glad I can help.